# Removing/Deleting all listeners to mousewheel event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

I have multiple section scrollers on a single page. Due to this lots of **mousewheel** events get triggered which results in slowness/ not so smooth scrolling of page when scrolling with mousewheel.

I tried throttling this event that improved performance a little bit.
Then I figured out removing the `eventlistener` from devtools for `mousewheel` event, then the scroller works fine and smooth too.
I am trying to achieve from code and facing issues with what to pass the second argument to `removeEventListener`.

```
  let rootPageRef = document.getElementById("page");
  if(rootPageRef){
   rootPageRef.removeEventListener('mousewheel', **?**);
  }
```

[image: remove browser default mousewheel listeners]

Comment: This seems potentially like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'd first want to find out why so many event listeners are on mousewheel. Is it intentional or is there somewhere the same listener keeps getting added?

Comment: I'm having multiple router outlets/ sections in page. So when doing mousewheel lots of wheel events gets triggered. The listeners are not from my code, they are inherited or browser defaults applied. So when manually removing listeners from devtools in page/target div, scrolling happens smooth. Now i'd want to remove the same listener or completely delete mousewheel event from code for the same page div. The problem is what second argument shall i pass to remove the listener attached by browser and not by me.

Answer (score 0):

As it was not possible to delete the mousewheel event listener over document. So I stopped the propagation from the main page. Now event bubbling is stopped and listeners do not execute for any of its parents/ancestors.

```
//prevent mousewheel event bubbling up from main page. This is to stop the propagation so ancestor event listeners over mousewheel won't execute and
// fill up call back queue
let rootPageRef = document.querySelector(".main-page");
if(rootPageRef){
  rootPageRef.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```